# Automatically set `fill-column' based on flake8 setup

Tags: python, fill-column

How can I automatically set `fill-column` based on flake8 configuration for `python-mode` buffers, specifically the `max-line-length` value in `.flake8`? Solutions that employs existing extensions are welcome.

Comment: Can you supply us with a shell command (something built into flake8?) which will read and output that value?

Comment: @phils I don't know what command would do that and I couldn't find one. Perhaps I should go to flake8 team and request such a feature.

Comment: I imagine flake8 is using some such thing behind the scenes to read its config.  You could do it in elisp, but I couldn't immediately find an elisp parser for that conf format, so I don't know whether that exists.  You *could* just do a simple text search for the expected `max-line-length` entry, though, which would probably be "good enough".  Perhaps you could add an example `.flake8` file to the question.

Comment: As an alternative, you could of course add a `.dir-locals.el` file in the same location, if you didn't mind the duplication (although my impression is that the duplication is precisely what you're looking to avoid).

Comment: @phils Yes, that is correct. The point is that when Emacs opens a file in a project, it should automatically detect the `max-line-length` settings by flake8 to avoid manually setting up every time.

Comment: FWIW you could probably hack together a solution with a `python-mode-hook` function which uses `locate-dominating-file` to look for a `flake8` file and, if it finds one, does a simple regexp search for `^max-line-length=\([0-9]+\)` (or whatever the expected syntax is), and does `(setq-local fill-column (string-to-number (match-string 1)))` if there was a match.